Characters on image of measure algebra under unitary representation
Let $\pi$ be a unitary representation of $G=SL(2,R)$ on a Hilbert space $H$. Let $M$ be the convolution algebra consisting of finite Borel measures on $G$ that are bi-K invariant where $K=SO(2)$. Let $A$ be the operator norm closure of $\pi(M)$ in the space of bounded operators on $H$. Let $\chi$ be a character on $A$. In section 3.1 in the paper “Pointwise ergoidic theorems for radial averages on simple Lie groups” (Duke Math J. 1994), the author claims that it is well known that there exists a spherical function $\phi_1$ so that for each bi-K invariant $f \in L^1(G)$ we have $\chi \circ \pi(f dm) = \int_G f(g) \phi_1(g) dm(g)$ where $dm$ is Haar measure.
The author refers the reader to the CIMPA notes of Faraut and to the book DG-LG-SS by Helgason. But I can’t find this statement in either. Is anyone familiar with this statement and would you know of a reference?
